# Add date header to incoming email with Sieve

Tags: email, sieve-language

I'm looking for a way to do in Sieve something that I've been doing in Procmail for years, which is to insert an unambiguous date header in incoming messages that makes it clear to me -- independent of buried "received" headers from possibly multiple servers and however my mail client interprets the date the message was sent -- when my server received the message. This is how I did it in Procmail:

```
# First create the "date_received" variable for my time zone:
date_received=`/bin/date -ud '+2 hour' +'%A %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +0200'`

# Second, insert the header containing the date_received variable:
:0 fh w
| formail -i "X-Local-Date-Received: $date_received"
```

I found "addheader" ([RFC 5293](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5293)) which will, obviously, add a header, but due to something else I read (sorry, don't remember where) I believe that Sieve won't run the "date" command in the shell due to either a limitation or an intended (and understandable) preference not to run shell commands for security reasons.

Other possibly useful information: I'm doing this through Roundcube 1.3.6, but I have a feeling ([also due to something I read](http://roundcube-webmail.10982.n7.nabble.com/managesieve-and-editheader-extension-td14598.html)) that Roundcube might overwrite a custom Sieve filter set if I edit the raw code within Roundcube. If necessary I'm quite happy to edit or create a Sieve configuration file on the server directly to achieve this for all users on the server, but having run Sendmail and Procmail for years I'm unsure of the best place to do this.

EDIT:

As a test in Roundcube I added this at the top of my Sieve filter set:

```
require ["fileinto","editheader"];
# rule:[test editheader]
if true
{
addheader "X-Test-Header" "This is a test header.";
}
```

I didn't actually add the line "require ["fileinto","editheader"];"; I just added "editheader" to the existing line at the top of the filter set, like so:

```
require ["copy","fileinto","regex","editheader"];
```

I expect this to add ...

```
X-Test-Header: This is a test header.
```

... to every incoming message, but Roundcube won't let me save it:

```
An error occurred.
Unable to save filter. Server error occurred.
```

[image: Roundcube error editing Sieve filter set.]

A search for this error returns one related result, with no solution posted.

I'm not intending to focus on Roundcube, however. Like I said earlier, I'll add this Sieve filter from the command line if necessary.

Comment: I'm a little confused (as I've not used Roundcube), but my understanding is that it's an IMAP *client*. While it will let you set the Sieve rules, their interpretation (and allowable extensions to do things like run code directly) would be handled by the IMAP *server*. What IMAP server are you running? Are you the administrator and able to edit its configuration?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Thanks for asking and sorry for the confusion, but like I said, my reference to Roundcube, while taking up a lot of space, is incidental to the main question about Sieve. I understand the difference between the client and the server, but my lack of knowledge and experience is with Sieve. The server is Dovecot 2.2.32 with Pigeonhole Sieve and ManageSieve and yes, I am root.

Comment: I tried to edit my question to add the version of Dovecot that I'm using, but I can't seen to do that. The system only shows me my past edits.

Answer (score 1):

The Pigeonhole Sieve Editheader extension isn't available by default. Per [its documentation](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Extensions/Editheader), you need to ensure it's added in your list of sieve extensions on the server:

```
plugin {
  # Use editheader
  sieve_extensions = +editheader
}
```

If you want to run arbitrary scripts using sieve on Dovecot like you can with procmail, then you can use its [external programs plugins](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/Extprograms), configure in Dovecot which external programs you want to allow users to use, and then the users can use the "vnd.dovecot.execute" extension to run those programs. You might be able to use this to port over whatever scripts you used with procmail.

In the general case, the purpose of sieve is for users to be able to configure their own mail filtering, while it seems like you're trying to actually do something globally for the server. Dovecot should add its own Received header when it processes the mail, which is the standard method for marking when a mail system gets a message, so it's not clear to me why you're not just using that, or what changes you want to make to its default behavior. It may be that what you're looking to do may be better handled in your mail transport agent rather than in your mail delivery agent.

Comment: Thanks This looks exactly like what I need. Please give me a few days to get to this and I will come back with the results and accept your answer, assuming it works.

Comment: As for why I'm doing this, there are fewer than a dozen users on this server, so I'm not doing it for thousands and don't mind if those few users have access to it, even though I'll probably be the only one who uses it. I know I can look at Dovecot's "Received:" headers for the information I want, but if I can programmatically put that information (already converted to the time zone where I am located at any given moment) in a separate header that I can display in my MUA by default, I get the information instantly.

Comment: Travelling between and corresponding with people in different time zones makes this very helpful.

When I first did this years ago I did it in the MDA/LDA because it made sense to me at the time, and the idea probably occurred to me when I was studying Procmail documentation. I probably should have thought of doing it in the MTA (Postfix now, Sendmail back then), and perhaps I'll look into it now to see if it's a better approach or more straightforward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sieve script that converts `Received` to `Date`:

```
require "editheader";
require "regex";
require "variables";

if not exists "Date" { 
    if header :regex "Received" "^from[[:space:]]+.*[[:space:]]+by[[:space:]]+mail.mydomain.com[[:space:]]+with[[:space:]]+.*[[:space:]]+for[[:space:]]+.*;(.*)$" {
        addheader :last "Date" "${1}";
    }
}
```

Note that `mail.mydomain.com` is a stand-in for the actual mail server address, which means it only matches the header when the message was received on a specific mail server. I made this work with dovecot-2.3.5.1

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Obviously I haven't got back to this since the other answer was suggested six months ago, but it is still on my radar. I presume I can use another header name, such as my "X-Local-Date-Received" instead of "Date", right?

Comment: I don't see why not. I am using `Date` since some emails get sorted in 1970 if they are missing the field

Comment: OK, thanks. Was just checking to ensure there wasn't a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date` plugin.  See: [rfc5260](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5260#section-4.2):

```
require "date";
require "editheader";

if currentdate :matches "std11" "*" {
    addheader :last "X-Local-Date-Received" "${1}";
}
```